# Why won't Angular-ui-router's <templateUrl> work when all my files are hosted in S3 bucket?

Tags: angularjs, facebook, amazon-s3, angular-ui-router, single-page-application

I'm building a sample AngularJS single-page application that uses Angular-UI-Router. But instead of the usual setup where the Angular application is served up through a web-server, I am running a server-side application that just serves up the index.html page in response to HTTP requests. All other resources needed are just pointers to my AWS S3 bucket or somewhere else.

I am doing this because I want to pre-populate the  tags on the server-side with `og:title` from my database so that the Facebook scraper sees the proper values (as I discussed [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44603496/how-can-single-page-angularjs-app-set-og-meta-tags-for-facebook-opengraph-in-t)). This can't be done purely on the user's client. That's why I have to jump through these hoops.

So when you curl my endpoint, it responds with the following HTML from my index page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <base href="/">
        <meta property="og:title" content="Saqib's Pre-filled OG Title!"/>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="pangolinApp">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><a ui-sref="splash"><button>Splash</button></a></td>
                <td><a ui-sref="blue"><button>Blue</button></a></td>
                <td><a ui-sref="green"><button>Green</button></a></td>
                <td><a ui-sref="red"><button>Red</button></a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <ui-view></ui-view>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/1.0.3/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://static.predictagram.com/js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://static.predictagram.com/js/splashController.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://static.predictagram.com/js/blueController.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://static.predictagram.com/js/greenController.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://static.predictagram.com/js/redController.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

It renders onto the page as expected. Great:

[image]

Here are the ui-router states specified in [**http://static.predictagram.com/js/app.js**](http://static.predictagram.com/js/app.js):

```
var app = angular.module("pangolinApp", ["ui.router"]);
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $stateProvider
    .state('splash', {url:'/', templateUrl : "html/splash.html", controller : "SplashCtrl"}) 
    .state('blue', {url:'/blue', template: '<p>Hello From Blue!!</p> <p>Color = {{color}}</p>', controller : "BlueCtrl"}) 
    .state('green', {url:'/green', templateUrl: 'html/green.html', controller : "GreenCtrl"})
    .state('red', {url:'/red', templateUrl: 'html/red.html', controller : "RedCtrl"});
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

However, the problem is that only the **Blue** button actually works. The other ones don't. I can see that when you press each button it enters the respective controller (because I have put a console.log line in each one). But only the template specified for the `blue` state is working.

Clearly this is because the `blue` state uses `template` and all the other states uses `templateUrl`. So I suspect it cannot find the files [`html/red`](http://static.predictagram.com/html/red.html), [`html/green`](http://static.predictagram.com/html/green.html). [`html/splash.html`](http://static.predictagram.com/html/splash.html). Maybe they are not being served? I don't know. How can I ensure my AngularJS Single-Page-App can access those html templates??

**EDIT:**
Here is pic of the structure of my angular application. But it is stored in my S3 bucket. So replace `angular_app/` with **http://static.predictagram.com/**:
[image]

Comment: can you please insert your app structure here? it's much better if you set the `templateUrl` starting from app `root`, for example `templateUrl: '/applicaion/partials/home.html'`

Comment: Maher, I added that to the original question. Thanks!

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38921884/how-get-a-template-from-a-remote-url-with-angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38921884/how-get-a-template-from-a-remote-url-with-angularjs)

Answer (score 0):

When you set templateUrl as: `templateUrl: 'html/green.html'` you are telling angular, that your templates can be found at that local folder (html).
As you are trying to take the templates from a remote server, you have to get them with absolute routes. For example: `templateUrl: 'http://yourserver/templates/green.html'`

As it is not meant to work like that, you are going to have CORS errors, you can take a look to this question/answer and it may help you:
[How get a template from a remote URL with AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38921884/how-get-a-template-from-a-remote-url-with-angularjs)